# How to show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0, + \infty)$ aren't homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

> Show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0, + \infty)$ aren't homeomorphic.

My first idea was to maybe use a connectedness argument, but I realised that if we take out an element from either set, both become non connected.

Something tells me that the proof should be elementary but I am unable to see it for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good idea!

Take out $0$ from $[0,\infty)$ and $f(0)$ from $\mathbb R$ where $f$ denotes the homeomorphism (that we assume to exist).

This results in connected space $(0,\infty)$ and not connected space $\mathbb R-\{f(0)\}$, so a contradiction is found.

Comment: Oh that's right, I should have been more precise in my choice of point! Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Hint :}$

Take $0$ from $[0,\infty)$ and see the connected components from both space :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that a homeomorphism would have to be an order isomorphism or anti-isomorphism (meaning, the order gets reversed). This is because a continuous injective function is necessarily order preserving.

But these orders are neither isomorphic or not anti-isomorphic (look at the end-points).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists a  homeomorphism $f: [0,\infty) \to  \mathbb R.$
Let $p = f(0).$ Then $g : (0,\infty)\to\mathbb R\setminus\{p\}$  defined by $g=f\mid_{(0,\infty)}$ is also a homemorphism.

However, $(0,\infty)$ is connected and $\mathbb R\setminus\{p\}$ is not. So you get a contradiction.